# Plugin init hook fires repeatedly

Tags: plugins, init

I 've just noticed that the init event of a plugin I write myself keeps firing every minute or so if any dashboard's page is loaded in the browser, without interacting with it or even focus on it.

Is this behavior expected? I cant find any information about it, am I missing something ?

Comment: The `init` event is fired every time WordPress is initialized, both front end and backend (wp-admin). What do you mean with "dashboard's page" and with "without interacting with it or even focus on it"?

Comment: I don't know if I can be more explanatory, but I' ll try. If I leave any admin/backend page loaded on a browser's tab, the init event keeps firing even if the tab is not active/focused. Of course no other page of the specific WP installation is opened neither backend nor frontend.

Comment: Your dashboard regularly makes Ajax requests, that's triggering the `init` most probably. Have a look at the network tab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because you are not excluding ajax requests.

Check this example from [the WordPress Codex for the `admin_init` hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init) which is also valid for the `init` hook and see how AJAX requests are exluded in the `if` using the `DOING_AJAX` constant:

```
/**
 * Restrict access to the administration screens.
 *
 * Only administrators will be allowed to access the admin screens,
 * all other users will be shown a message instead.
 *
 * We do allow access for Ajax requests though, since these may be
 * initiated from the front end of the site by non-admin users.
 */
function restrict_admin() {

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && ( ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) || ! DOING_AJAX ) ) {
        wp_die( __( 'You are not allowed to access this part of the site' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'restrict_admin', 1 );
```

You can use this as a starting point:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_182220_init' );
function wpse_182220_init() {

    // Exit function if doing an AJAX request
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {
        return;
    }

    echo 'OK, not doing AJAX';

}
```

Props to [RRikesh](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/182220/plugin-init-hook-fires-repeatedly/182227#comment266254_182220) for mentioning it in his comment.

Comment: very nice solution - I've been looking for that few hours ;)